# toggle the value of variable that is being watched in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, watch

I have a data variable whose typeof is boolean and I have put this in watch hook. On changing the value to `true` , I'm performing some tasks in watch like this and it's working perfectly.

```
watch: {
   boolVar: function (val) {
     if(val === true){
       //doing some tasks
     }
   }
}
```

Then I started to integrate some other stuff and requirement is to toggle the variable in case if it's already true because i want to perform the same tasks with watcher.
Suppose, on a certain point `boolVar` is already `true` and I have to run the watcher again then what should I do?

Previously, I was toggling the `boolVar` like this

```
//in some other function
if(this.boolVar === true){
  this.boolVar = false;
  this.boolVar = true;
}
```

It was supposed to work as watcher will listen and perform the functionality in the watcher on value change when it's true.
But, It's not working as I was expecting.

So, after some trials, I get to know that there is a difference/mismatch in time delay on which watcher is listening that is why my code was not working.

Then I tried this methodology (by using sleep and promise methodology so that after 1 Milli seconds watcher can listen) and It's working again with my requirement.

```
//in some other function
//now function is async to use await

if(this.boolVar === true){
  this.boolVar = false;
  await this.sleep(1);
  this.boolVar = true;
}
```

```
//sleep function
sleep(ms) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
},
```

Is there any best approach to handle this? in case where you want to toggle the variable that is being watched and perform some tasks again? Because currently, my hack is working but I think watcher should detect when you toggle the same variable (as I was expecting but it's not detecting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Vue.$nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick).

```
if(this.boolVar === true){
  this.boolVar = false;
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.boolVar = true;
  })
}
```

If you don't want to use $nextTick, you can do like that :

```
  watch: {
    boolVar: {
      handler(val) {
        console.log(val)
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
```

However, why don't you just make a doSomeWork() function, call it in your watcher, and when you need to re-execute that logic, you call the function rather than toggling your boolean? That would make more sense to me, but maybe I'm missing some details. :

```
watch: {
   boolVar: function (val) {
     if(val === true){
       this.doingSomeTasks()
     }
   }
}
```

And :

```
if(this.boolVar === true){
  this.doingSomeTasks()
}
```

Comment: 1) about first solution that you have suggested, it's also equivalent to 1millisecond to perform the command. (it's equivalent)
2) for the second one, I can't assume when `boolVar === true` and on this perform `this.doingSomeTasks()` because it is the reason why I'm watching this `boolVar` because value can be changed from anywhere.  (It's not worth it)

What I want is not to wait for the 1MilliSecond sleep or nexttick or settimeout etc
I want something that can detect toggle of value

Comment: Another ( strange ) solution would be to use the "deep" property. I edited my answer, read it again and tell me if it is ok for you

Comment: I have tried with deep as well, but nothing happened because I think it's for the object and it's attributes. Anyhow I get to know this problem is related to async and sync. marking as accepted answer as you included some approaches towards the problem.

Comment: But I hope there should be some mechanism that can detect the changes even under the 1 MilliSeconds or refresh the queue as soon as there is abrupt changes

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work as you expect because you expect that all `watch` handlers are executed synchronously but they are not. Vue is using [Async Update Queue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue)

> Whenever a data change is observed, it will open a queue and buffer all the data changes that happen in the same event loop. If the same watcher is triggered multiple times, it will be pushed into the queue only once. This buffered de-duplication is important in avoiding unnecessary calculations and DOM manipulations. Then, in the next event loop “tick”, Vue flushes the queue and performs the actual (already de-duped) work.

This means that when you execute `this.boolVar = false;this.boolVar = true;` - both changes are just "registered" by Vue. When all your code finished executing, "next event loop" starts - Vue sees the change in the queue, finds the registered watcher and checks the old (= value when the handler was last executed) and new value. Which are in your case both `true` ...so from the Vue point of view there is no change and no need to execute the handler....

From technical POV the solution is to postpone 2nd change (`this.boolVar = true;`) to some later "tick" so Vue "sees" the `false` 1st and in the next tick it will run the watcher (`false` -> `true`)

**But** good code is not just the code that works but also the code that is communicating programmer's intent and is easy to understand. `this.boolVar = false;this.boolVar = true;` is violating this principle in a big way

You need to run `someTasks` when your variable changes from `false` to `true`. That's fine. But you also want to run `someTasks` in other scenario when the variable is already `true`. It is clear that `someTasks` **should not be in the watcher** but extracted to independent method as @Julien already suggested...

**Update** ...just to be complete

What you want is possible in Vue 3 with the new `flush` option of the [watch](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-data.html#watch) - just use value `sync` and your watcher will be executed synchronously anytime the value changes. See the demo below...

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      value: true,
      flushMode: 'sync',
      unwatch: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.value = false
      this.value = true
    }
  },
  watch: {
    flushMode: {
      handler: function() {
        this.unwatch && this.unwatch()
        this.unwatch = this.$watch('value', 
          function(newValue) {
            console.log(`New value = ${newValue}`)
          }, 
          { flush: this.flushMode }
        )
      },
      immediate: true    
    }
  },
  updated() {
    console.log('Component updated')
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.1.1/vue.global.prod.min.js" integrity="sha512-vRIbP8hGYYKnayuLhVRwQXTxvAJ/wUm4vqIEzIBKLfDcM2ArSENuojG1jEIactQ7F/0unOe9VQ+U9KagTEyQvA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    Variable: {{ value }}
  </div>
  <button @click="toggle">Toggle</button>
  <div>
    <label for="pre">Flush mode:</lael>
    <input type="radio" id="pre" value="pre" v-model="flushMode" /> pre (default)
    <input type="radio" id="sync" value="sync" v-model="flushMode" /> sync
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice to know the information on it. Thanks :) Upvoted